# READONLY attribute not being assigned to PHP variable

Tags: php, get, readonly

I am assigning two variables based on a GET key value pair. The first variable gets set, the second one does not:

```
$amt=isset($_GET['a']) ? $_GET['a'] : 0;
$alk=isset($_GET['a']) ? " readonly=\"READONLY\"" : "";
```

...

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"amount\" size=\"5\" class=\"inputbox\" value=\"".$amt."\"".$alk.">";
```

The input field gets the default value from what gets passed in the URL's ?a=100 key-value pair, but the readonly attribute does not get applied. Suggestions?

Comment: How do you check whether it applied or not?

Comment: `readonly` attribute does not need a value.

Comment: wrong name attribute. `amount` and not `a`.

Comment: `$alk=isset($_GET['amount']) ? " readonly=\"READONLY\"" : "";`

Comment: Your code works here - https://3v4l.org/QFblD. Is there something in `...` that you are not showing us that reassigns `$alk`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- OP has `URL's ?a=100 key-value pair`, so I am guessing they are reassigning the `a` value to the `amount` input.

Comment: @Sean Hard to say as to the name attribute for it. OP's not interacting here, so I'll just disappear too ;-)

Comment: I take a look at the HTML output, and the readonly attribute is missing, but the value is assigned.

Comment: There is only other code marked by the ellipses. I don't touch the $amt or $alk values after the initial assignment.

Answer (score -1):

W3C says, "In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the readonly attribute must be defined as readonly="readonly" />". So I closed the input box with forward-slash-close-angle-bracket and the readonly attribute now works. Thanks.